# fortran 77 and 90 mpi libraries

Tags: openmpi

I compiled openmpi-1.8 using,

shell$ ./configure --prefix=$(pwd) CC=gcc CXX=g++ F77=gfortran FC=gfortran

shell$ make all install

However, I did not see libmpi_f77.so and libmpi_f90.so library files in lib directory. Any ways to obtain these library files.

Appreciate your help.

-Raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fortran routines of Open MPI 1.8 are contained in `libmpi_mpifh.so.2` and `libmpi_usempi*.so.0`.

Comment: Do you know if there is there a way to link the new versions to a binary application that was compiled with `libmpi_f90.so.1`?

Comment: @JonatanÖström, I don't think so. The separation of the library into multiple files most likely resulted in symbols changing names too. Besides, internal structures might have changed. It is best to find a way to recompile and relink the code.

Comment: I don't have the source. But I realized that from the OpenMPI homepage, one can download and compile any previous version of the library.